# A Rook's Territory in the Chessboard

Tags: checkerboard, polyomino

Shade 32 cells, four on each row and column, of an 8 x 8 blank chessboard (all its cells originally white) so that a rook sitting on any shaded cell can reach any other shaded cell, moving just along other shaded cells.

If not possible, what is the size of the largest square board on which this can be done, i.e. shading four cells of each row and column creating a connected territory for a rook lying on any of its cells.

Problem based on a similar one communicated by Stan Wagon (http://stanwagon.com/pow/), who asks whether 3 cells of each row and column can be so shaded in a *n* x *n* (*n* > 4) board.

Comment: The problem with 3 cells and $n>4$ is *The American Mathematical Monthly* problem 12137 (October 2019).

Comment: I had trouble understanding the problem because I imagine the rook jumping from the start to the destination cell.  You should make clear that all the cells between the start and the end of each move must be shaded.  The shaded region must be orthogonally connex.

Comment: @FlorianF: No, orthogonally convex is too strong.

Comment: @RobPratt Would you please transcribe statement of AMM problem?

Comment: @BernardoRecamánSantos https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2018S-3903/12008.pdf

Comment: I said othogonally connex, not convex.

Comment: Connex doesn't seem to be the right term, according to [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connex_relation). "Orthogonally connected" probably gets the point across well enough.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a typo like *othogonally*. 

Comment: This is now (roughly) Problem 12244 in the April 2021 issue of The Amrican Mathematical Monthly.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I started with this:

> ```
>  - - X X X X - -
>  - - X X X X - -
>  X X - - - - X X
>  X X - - - - X X
>  X X - - - - X X
>  X X - - - - X X
>  - - X X X X - -
>  - - X X X X - -
> ```

Pushed things this way and that, ended up with this:

> ```
>  - - - X X X - X
>  X - X X - - - X
>  X X X - - - - X
>  X - X - - - X X
>  X X - - X - X -
>  - X - - X X X -
>  - X X X - X - -
>  - - - X X X X -
> ```

Similarly, on 9x9:

> ```
>  - - - X X X - - X
>  - - X X X - - - X
>  X X X - - - - - X
>  X X - - - - - X X
>  X - - - - X X X -
>  X X - - - X - X -
>  - X X - - - X X -
>  - - X X X - X - -
>  - - - X X X X - -
> ```

And on 10x10:

> ```
>  - - X X X X - - - -
>  - - - X X X X - - -
>  - - - - X - X X - X
>  X - - - - - - X X X
>  X X - - - - - - X X
>  X X - - - - - - X X
>  X X - - - - - X X -
>  - X X - - - X X - -
>  - - X X - X X - - -
>  - - X X X X - - - -
> ```

It took me a while to get there, but that one suggests an emerging pattern.

And here is an expandable solution for any $2n\times 2n$ grid.

> [image]

Comment: Great! Is this the largest square board on which this can be done?

Comment: @Bernardo 9x9 and 10x10 Is there a limit?

Comment: @Daniel Matias Don´t know!

Comment: @Bernardo $2n\times 2n$, unlimited. Probably something similar for $2n+1$, but I'm done for now.

Answer (score 22):

Here's an expandable solution for $n\ge 5$ (even or odd):

> [image]

Comment: Looks good for all $n\ge 5$

Comment: Truly beautiful!!

Comment: n = 4 is trivial; fill the grid. n < 4 is trivially impossible.